# Make image overflow its container?

Tags: css, overflow, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make two "layouts"; one where the image adapt width to its container and one where the image overflow it. The latter is a tricky one. I haven't been able to come up with a neat solution yet. I've tried flexbox and position:absolute to get the element vertical aligned but it just ends up in a mess most of the time. I'm not really satisfied with the result.

**Some requirements if possible:**

1) No use of position:absolute;

2) Elements needs to be vertical align middle in some way

[image: This one is quite easy to achieve:]

**What I want to achieve:**
[image: Here it stats to get difficult:]

Comment: You should use negative margins on the images and make sure the container has `overflow:visible`. Negative margins can be expressed in `%` or `vw` (vieport width percentage), in case that helps you. If you plan on placing content above the image, make sure you set `position: relative` and `z-index` on both the image and the overlay-ed content.

Comment: Hi, were you able to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to this problem can be achieved using `display: table` for the container element and `display: table-cell` to vertically center the two divs. Then, you just have to give your images a negative margin on the left/right and set the container to `overflow: visible` (or `hidden`, as you like).

Requirements fulfilled.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.cell {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.container .image,
.container .content {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container .image {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/300);
  height: 150px;
}
.container .content {
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-right {
  float: right;
}
.col-left {
  float: left;
}
.container.hard .image {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/400);
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}
.container.hard .image.image-left {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.container.hard .image.image-right {
  margin-right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Easy Part</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="content col-right">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="content col-left">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Hard Part</h1>
<div class="container hard">
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="image image-left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="content col-right">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container hard">
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="content col-left">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="image image-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it in JSFiddle but it didn't seem to work as expected? https://jsfiddle.net/y4yxxzc6/

Comment: You forgot the last two rules of my CSS :)

Comment: Sorry my bad! Thanks a lot!